# how to use Maven Assembly plugin in Multimodule Projects

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multimodule maven project like :

```
Main Module
   Module A
   Module B
   Module C
```

when i build the Main module it will produce the following:

```
Main Module
   Module A
       target/A.jar
   Module B
       target/B.jar
   Module C
       target/C.jar
```

i need an assembly descriptor to zip all child artifacts (A.jar, B.jar, C.jar here) in a file :

```
My.zip
   - A.jar
   - B.jar
   - C.jar
```

any idea ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this...  Refer to [this link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html) for details.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>distribution</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <moduleSets>
    [...]
    <moduleSet>
      <includes>
        <include>${project.groupId}:A</include>
        <include>${project.groupId}:B</include>
        <include>${project.groupId}:C</include>
      </includes>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
  [...]
</assembly>
```